# Bootstrap not showing up on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing Hartl's railstutorial and I'm on chapter 5

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-custom_css

I'm adding bootstrap to the website but for it's not showing up for me. Instead, it's showing up as if I never added bootstrap at all. I added the gem and bundle installed and created a file app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss and put

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

into the file. I then restarted the server, but nothing different shows up. If it makes a difference, I'm on windows.

Comment: import is only working with sass/scss. What is file extension of your application.css? It should be application.scss or application.sass to serve import.

Comment: It's just application.css - I changed it to application.css.scss but that didn't help. Unless I had to rake or something? im new to rails

Comment: Have you added require_self in your application.css.scss file?

Comment: Yeah. I figured out the problem. It was in my application.html.erb